# Does the path integral measure have dimension?

Tags: path-integral, dimensional-analysis

For example, in the field functional integral:

$$\int D\phi \ e^{S[\phi]} $$

Does the  $D\phi$ here have dimensions?

Comment: It might help if you were state some context of the integral.  Maybe its a famous integral that I don't recognize, but writing some context will help both answers and people who might search for this problem in the future.

Comment: @ReidErdwien: It is a [path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). (but I agree with you the question should've been clear about that)

Comment: Sorry for that, just a normal path integral
$Z=\int D\phi \ e^{S[\phi]}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the path integral measure has units but they are mostly irrelevant because physically well-defined objects tend to be ratios of path integrals in which the basic portion cancels, along with its units. So the overall normalization factor in front of the path integral (including its units) drops out.

But the path integral measure should be assigned the same units as
$$ d^\chi \phi $$
where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of the manifold on which $\phi$ is defined. In this sense, $\chi$ acts as the "regulated number of points" on the target manifold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was just thinking about the Helmholtz Free Energy $F=Log(Z)$, so I would guess that the partition function is dimensionless.

Comment: In principle, one can imagine the logarithm of dimensionful things as well - but they produce things like bizarre additive log(meter) terms. But in quantum mechanics, there is a reason why you are right: one computes the path integral over a spacetime with a thermal circle. And the Euler character of $A\times B$ is $\chi_A\times \chi_B$, and because $\chi$ of a (thermal or other) circle $S^1$ is zero, $\chi=0$. In classical statistical physics, one must be more careful about the normalization  factors in front of $Z$ when going in the continuum limit.